# Ambiguous use of operator "+"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, backwards-compatibility

So I have this little algorithm in my Xcode project and it no longer works - it's telling me that I can't add a number to another number, no matter what I try.

Note:
Everything was working perfectly before I changed my target to *iOS 7.0*.
I don't know if that has anything to do with it, but even when I switched it back to *iOS 8* it gave me an error and my build failed.

**Code:**

```
var delayCounter = 100000

for loop in 0...loopNumber {
    let redDelay: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000

    let blueDelay: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000

    let yellowDelay: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000

    let greenDelay: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trouble is that `delayCounter` is an `Int`, but `arc4random_uniform` returns a `UInt32`.  You either need to declare `delayCounter` as a `UInt32`:

```
var delayCounter: UInt32 = 100000
let redDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000
```

or convert the result of `arc4random` to an `Int`:

```
var delayCounter:Int = 100000
let redDelay = NSTimeInterval(Int(arc4random_uniform(100000)) + delayCounter) / 30000
```

Answer (score 5):

The function `arc4random_uniform` returns a `UInt32`, but `delayCounter` is of type `Int`.
There is no operator definition for `+` in Swift, which takes a `UInt32` and `Int` as its parameters though. Hence Swift doesn't know what to do with this occurrence of the `+` operator - it's `ambiguous`.

Therefore you'll have to cast the `UInt32` to an `Int` first, by using an existing initializer of `Int`, which takes a `UInt32` as its parameter:

```
let redDelay:    NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(Int(arc4random_uniform(100000)) + delayCounter) / 30000
let blueDelay:   NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(Int(arc4random_uniform(100000)) + delayCounter) / 30000
let yellowDelay: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(Int(arc4random_uniform(100000)) + delayCounter) / 30000
let greenDelay:  NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(Int(arc4random_uniform(100000)) + delayCounter) / 30000
```

A different approach would be to declare `delayCounter` as a `UInt32`:

```
let delayCounter: UInt32 = 100000
```

Answer (score 1):

`arc4random_uniform` function returns `UInt32`. You need to convert it to `Int`

**Function declaration**
`func arc4random_uniform(_: UInt32) -> UInt32`

**Solution :**
    let redDelay:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(Int(arc4random_uniform(100000)) + delayCounter) / 30000